# If I have an unknown pointer reference to a certain type, how do I get the underlying certain type?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, pointers, types

I am using the following code:

```
Type type = info.ParameterType;
object activatedType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
arguments[info.Position] = activatedType;
```

The problem is that `type` may end up being a pointer reference to a certain type, like `System.String&` (note the &), so how can I get the underlying type of `System.String`?

Essentially, how do I dereference an unknown type to its underlying type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(type.IsByRef)
{
   type = type.GetElementType();
}
```

If you want to get a reference type from another type, you can use [MakeByRefType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.makebyreftype.aspx):

```
Type stringRefType = typeof(string).MakeByRefType();
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a fast way to go about doing the exact opposite, whereby you create a type reference?

Comment: @Alexandru - Yes, you can use `MakeByRefType` - I've updated the answer.

Comment: But that returns a Type, does it not? Isn't that different from wanting it to be a pointer to a type? I guess, shouldn't it be an object?

Comment: I've tried activatedType = Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType().MakeByRefType());

But it complains that no constructor was defined for this object, since it is of enumerable type.

Comment: @Alexandru - It returns the type of a `string` parameter passed by reference e.g. `void SomeMethod(ref string str) { ... }`. I'm not really sure what you mean by wanting a 'pointer to a type'.

Comment: Like, after I activate the type as an object, I need to get a reference to that object. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: For example, 

object activatedTypeToReference = Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType());
activatedType = ??? // Create a pointer to the object that was activated above